# "&" causing problems in php searchquery

Tags: php, database, forms

So after grabbing data from my database,`$genrelisty=$row['genre']` One of the variables is "R & B" and when I try and search it in my database the resulting page s blank, when I search other genres like "Rap" or "Hip Hop" the resulting page works just fine and just shows the data related to the search.

in php there's a foreach and it echos all the data from the database that I want it to display like the title with `$title=$row['Title']` then in a big echo statement display everything with text that I want it t be with, There's a search featre at the top of my page which you can search spefic things like artist or genre and then type the artist name or genre, but whenever the search value is "R & B" or as the link "?searchLocation=genre&searchValue=R%20&%20B" but then I tried replacing '&' with 'n' on both post and get sites but the search result is noting currently the link is like "?searchLocation=genre&searchValue=RnB"

Comment: `R%20&%20B` is not properly url encoded. "&" in any uri means another get var will be created.

Comment: When I did a string rewrite to "n", it did not work but when the link said "searchValue=R+%26+B" it worked so instead of "n" I replaced it with "%26" and now works everytime, But for visuals sake, I want it to show R&B but set to "R %26 B".

Comment: How you display things in a web page can be different than how you put them into an URL (using a mix of urlencode, urldecode, htmlspecialchars, and the like). URL's are rarely visually friendly, especially with arbitrary search parameters not part of SEO url rewriting. So if you are trying to make a visually 'nice looking URL' with `?searchLocation=genre&searchValue=R&B` ... good luck ;)

Comment: Not a nice looking URL, I'd care less. I have the variables set to where it shows the same thing in the URL and in the page since the link is also replaced with a set variable.